# Compare file dates

Tags: 18.04, files, mate, copy

Sometimes when I boot, my system goes into emergency mode.

I then use Clonezilla to restore an image.

Usually the image is older than the current date.

This is part of a backup script that runs as a startup program.

```
cd /home/andy/bin/
zip -u -q Ubuntu_Scripts.zip *.sh *.rb *.c *.py *.txt
cp -u Ubuntu_Scripts.zip /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB1/Ubuntu_Mate_18.04/
cp -u Ubuntu_Scripts.zip /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB5/Emergency_Backup/
```

This then overwrites my zip file with one that is in fact older.

I thought that if I could compare the file dates, before the zip operation, I could prevent the overwriting.

I tried this.

```
file1time=`stat -c %Y /home/andy/bin/Ubuntu_Scripts.zip`

file2time=`stat -c %Y /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB1/Ubuntu_Mate_18.04/Ubuntu_Scripts.zip`

if [ "$file1time" -ot "$file2time" ]
then
 echo "File is older. "
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rsync` instead of `cp` and you can use the `--update` flag that will only update when you are copying a newer file.

```
cd /home/andy/bin/
zip -u -q Ubuntu_Scripts.zip *.sh *.rb *.c *.py *.txt
rsync -av --update Ubuntu_Scripts.zip /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB1/Ubuntu_Mate_18.04/
rsync -av --update Ubuntu_Scripts.zip /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB5/Emergency_Backup/
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code uses `-ot` where it should use `-lt`. See the example below.

```
#!/bin/bash

file1time=`stat -c %Y /home/niclas/dbat/INSTALL.txt`

file2time=`stat -c %Y /home/niclas/dbat/README.txt`

if [ "$file1time" -lt "$file2time" ]
then
    echo "INSTALL.txt is older."
else
    echo "README.txt is older."
fi
```